# two conditions multiplication in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

I have the following dataframe, and I am trying to get revenue column by a multiplication between columnA or columnB and columnC.

The condition is:

- if columnB is NaN, then the revenue column = columnA * columnC
- if columnB is not NaN, then the revenue column = columnB * columnC

```
type   columnA     columnB     columnC
1        23          NaN          2
2        14          35           3
3        11          NaN          4
4        29          12           5
```

how do I get this revenue column with these two condition in python? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can check if `columnB` contains any `NaN` values using `.isnull().values.any()` then apply an `if else` condition to get the desired `revenue` column.

Here's how you can do it:

```
df['revenue'] = df['columnA'] * df['columnC'] if df['columnB'].isnull().values.any() else df['columnB'] * df['columnC']
```

Output:

```
   type  columnA  columnB  columnC  revenue
0     1       23      NaN        2       46
1     2       14     35.0        3       42
2     3       11      NaN        4       44
3     4       29     12.0        5      145
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```py
import numpy as np


df['revenue'] = np.where(df['columnB'].isna(), df['columnA'] * df['columnC'], df['columnB'] * df['columnC'])
```

```
   type  columnA  columnB  columnC  revenue
0     1       23      NaN        2     46.0
1     2       14     35.0        3    105.0
2     3       11      NaN        4     44.0
3     4       29     12.0        5     60.0
```